# Repeating Multiple Rows Multiple Times in Excel VBA, with Calculations

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I have an excel sheet with data as per the image below:

[image: Input]

And I need to have it set out as follows:

[image: Output]

Could someone help me in coming up with an excel macro for this request, as there are numerous such rows and I am not so proficient with excel macros?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stackoverflow. This site is not a "develop this code for me" site but rather a site to help each other see where our code is not working.  What you are needed is achievable. Use a Loop which starts from the bottom of your list then inserts the number of rows depending on the value int the duration column, then divide the time difference by that number too and populate the times. Try is and post what you get here and we can have a look

Comment: You can apply shorting in VBA on first second and Third Column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my testing this does exactly what you asked for.

You will need to rename the Sheets depending on what your sheet names for the original data sheet name is and your output / result sheet name is.

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub splittinghours()

      Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
      Dim ResultSheet As Worksheet
      Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
      Set ResultSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

      Dim DataSheetLastRow As Long
      With DataSheet
          DataSheetLastRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
      End With

      Dim ActualWarehouse As String
      Dim ActualDate As String
      Dim InTime As Date
      Dim OutTime As Date
      Dim Duration As Long
      Dim CurrentRow As Long
      Dim DurationCounter As Long
      Dim SegmentedDuration As Date
      Dim ResultSheetNextFreeLine As Long

      ResultSheet.Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(ResultSheet.Rows.Count, ResultSheet.Columns.Count)).Delete

      ResultSheetNextFreeLine = 0

      For CurrentRow = 2 To DataSheetLastRow

           ActualWarehouse = DataSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, "A").Value
           ActualDate = DataSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, "B").Value
           InTime = DataSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, "C").Value
           OutTime = DataSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, "D").Value
           Duration = DataSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, "E").Value
           SegmentedDuration = (OutTime - InTime) / Duration

           ResultSheetNextFreeLine = ResultSheet.Cells(ResultSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

           For DurationCounter = 1 To Duration

                With ResultSheet

                    .Cells(ResultSheetNextFreeLine + DurationCounter, "A").Value = ActualWarehouse
                    .Cells(ResultSheetNextFreeLine + DurationCounter, "B").Value = ActualDate
                    .Cells(ResultSheetNextFreeLine + DurationCounter, "C").Value = InTime
                    .Cells(ResultSheetNextFreeLine + DurationCounter, "D").Value = InTime + SegmentedDuration
                     InTime = InTime + SegmentedDuration

                End With

           Next DurationCounter

      Next CurrentRow

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jean! However the below line was causing an error, which I commented it out. I believe it is to clear the result sheet before populating it. The code works just fine. Thanks a lot for your timely help

ResultSheet.Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(ResultSheet.Rows.Count, ResultSheet.Columns.Count)).Delete

Comment: @SrivathsanV good stuff, enjoy stackoverflow. Remember to mark correct and upvote the answers you select to your questions.